# Passing parameter to bean using CDI

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

I am new to CDI. I can't figure out how convert the following code using CDI.

```
Class Client {

  void method(){
    List<Events> events = getEvents();
    I b = new B(events); 
    I c = new C("Hello"); 
  }

 List<Events> getEvents(){
    //Do Something 
    return events;
  }
}

Class B implements I{

 List<Events> events ;

 B(List<Events> events){
    this.events = events; 
  }
}

Class C implements I{

 String s;
  C(String s){
    this.s = s; 
  }
}
```

I used Qualifiers to avoid ambiguity but can figure out how to pass parameters from the client.Do I need to use producer to inject the List and string into Class B and C respectively?

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) 
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
public @interface Ii {
Type value() ;
public enum Type {
      B,
      C 
  }

}


Class Client {
   @Inject @Ii(Ii.type.B)
   B b;
   @Inject @Ii(Ii.type.C)
   C b;

}

@Ii(Ii.type.B)
Class B { 

}

@Ii(Ii.type.C)
Class C {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare a Producer.

```
@Produces @Ii(Ii.type.B)
public void produceB {
  return Ii.type.B;
}

@Produces @Ii(Ii.type.C)
public void produceC {
  return Ii.type.C;
}
```

In Order to you events you need to annotate the parameter that should create events with `@Observes`. In the code below you can see how you get a list of fired events.

```
@Inject
private List<Event> events;
```

Comment: But how will Class B get List<Event>? Produces will just return new B().

Comment: I updated my answer with a code that allows you to access the list of events.